# DOM Parse table on complicated (to me) page

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I've spent couple hours reading stack overflow and trying get data from some webpage with no success.
Could You help me? I ran out of ideas.

here is the html:
[html](http://www.m.rozkladzik.pl/poznan/wyszukiwarka_polaczen.html?from=Szymanowskiego%7Cb%7C105&to=Rybaki%7Cb%7C90&profile=opt&maxWalkChange=400&minChangeTime=2&currTime=1)

I've tried lot of examples. And the last one been simplest I think; and still have no idea how to do this.

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

//new dom object
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        /*** get each column by tag name ***/
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        /*** echo the values ***/
        echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
        echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />';
        echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
        echo '<hr />';

    }
```

and I getting this:

> Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object
>   because $tables is empty.

I need to get only two positions like on this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: not this $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); this $tables = $html->getElementsByTagName('table');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.m.rozkladzik.pl/poznan/wyszukiwarka_polaczen.html?from=Szymanowskiego%7Cb%7C105&to=Rybaki%7Cb%7C90&profile=opt&maxWalkChange=400&minChangeTime=2&currTime=1');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$routes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' route_row ')]");

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $times[] = $routes->item($i);
}
```

$times is now an array with two DOMElement elements, that are the first two lines of the results.

Comment: Thx for reply :)
Unfonturnetly array result this:
 Array ( [0] => [1] => )

Comment: even when i change
`$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url)`
to
`$dom->loadHTMLFile($url)`

Comment: You probably changed something on the code, as I run it and I see that I have DOMElement objects in the array: Check my result: https://gyazo.com/21a118b1de9e44d497d9922143622ccc